# WebClients uploadstring

Tags: .net, webclient, uploadstring

I'm using the WebClient to post string to a WebApiController using UploadString.

The string Im uploading is an Xml file containing a DateTime in the following format: "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000+zzz".

The problem I encounter is that the string is sent ok but the endpoint ApiController gets the string without the "+" character in the DateTime. It is replaced with " ".

How can I format the Xml string so that I will get the "+" character in the ApiController?

I tried

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(xmlString)
```

but it didn't do anything.

Thanks a lot,

Rotem

Comment: Have you tried `Uri.EscapeDataString` ?

Comment: When you say it "didn't do anything" - did you just call it and expect it to change the existing string? Did you use the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string someData = "<foo>yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000+zzz</foo>";
string urlPart = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someData);
```

Gives:

```
%3cfoo%3eyyyy-mm-ddThh%3amm%3ass.000%2bzzz%3c%2ffoo%3e
```

which should work fine; the `%2b` is the encoded `+`. An alternative is:

```
string someData = "<foo>yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000+zzz</foo>";
string urlPart = Uri.EscapeDataString(someData);
```

which gives

```
%3Cfoo%3Eyyyy-mm-ddThh%3Amm%3Ass.000%2Bzzz%3C%2Ffoo%3E
```

which is *semantically identical* (it only differs in the case of the %-encoded tokens, but that doesn't matter). It should work fine either way.